# recyclerview onBind not working properly when Layouts are nested

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I was trying to implement a simple example of RecyclerView with items getting colored alternatively https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFmJi.jpg which worked fine
Without the Framelayout we are getting a clear coloring code as showed in first picture 
i.e. the items are colored in a particular pattern
however 
After adding the FrameLayout section i am getting issue that color code is not coming properly https://i.stack.imgur.com/phKNT.jpg

Technically what changed after addition of FrameLayout section

#### This is RecyclerView class onBindView code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(values.contains(position+1)){
        holder.textView1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));
        System.out.println("Color Check : "+values + " "+position);
    }
    String value = MyData[position];
    holder.textView1.setText(value);
}
```

#### This is RecyclerView xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Sample Items"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 1 :

the logic i need is item 1,3,6,10,15 should be colored (either the FrameLayout or textView ) 
the logic is working fine until FrameLayout in introduced in the xml layout of RecyclerView post which 
items that are getting colored are 1,3,6,8,10,13,15

Comment: Could you please provide your expected result. I don't see anything wrong in the image after adding FrameLayout. Do you want the entire card to have the color?

Comment: You should set color to the FrameLayout, not the TextView if you want the hole item to be colored...

Comment: there is no specific need to color the FrameLayout , i have tried that as well  the main concern is that the logic is not getting replicated , with Framelayout the addition the Recycler view is acting some odd way

Comment: When you say,"color code is not coming properly"., what do you mean precisely? Do you want the whole frame behind the textview  to be colored?....then do what @HedShafran is suggesting... and also Elaborate your comment, " Recycler view is acting some odd way" by editing your question

Comment: @nobalG I have i have added the Edit , the issue is not with the coloring the framelayout or textview , i have tried both however the order of items getting colored is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt get your logic but if its working when you are using the RecyclerView as a simples list instead of "cards", probably because the onBindViewHolder is just printing everything without recycle when you are using great amount of size on your list the recyclerview will try to reuse the content.

You can try this:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: worked like charm ,however i am still curious what happened , does this mean the code will not take the advantage of caching in case of RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

Another thing worked for me is one needs to put the condition for if and then else condition for remaining options 
I think its better solution than making holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        if(values.contains(position+1)){
            holder.textView1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));
        }else
        {
            holder.textView1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));
        }
        String value = MyData[position];
        holder.textView1.setText(value);
    }
```